# Deferred Lighting in 2D, how to add the light effects together

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I am currently using

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

but its not giving the desired effect. When one light is drawn on top of another, their effects are not added together around the edges. Instead, the darker light may cause the brighter lighted area to become darker!

How do I solve this problem?

[image: Lighting Artifacts]

Comment: Post actual rendering code, if you want help.